# fastest way to iterate through uneven columns to find the existing value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 DataFrames of (df1) 35k and (df2) 76k rows where I need to check whether `df1["col1"]` elements exist in `df2["col2"]` sub-elements. The code seems to be working fine on a sample dataset I have provided but the runtime takes forever on the original one. Here is a for-loop code I used on the sample dataset:

```
import pandas as pd

post_token_list = [['wXrL3TbK'], ['wXmTQKw1'], ['wXvnlWej'], ['wXvXBjKp']]
tokens_list = [['wXv3qoPQ', 'wXvT7ylu', 'wXvnIJuH', 'wXvXH7vy', 'wXvDXSS1', 'wXvjVE1F', 'wXvPV6z1', 'wXvHF1uw',
                'wXvH1q03', 'wXvnTlcr', 'wXvDEG9U', 'wXLfZtO6', 'wXvLDDDl', 'wXvHTgjk', 'wXvHDDr8', 'wXvPBLbu',
                'wXvvxXHI', 'wXvPBFge', 'wXvLxSii', 'wXvDhk2h', 'wXv3Alan', 'wXvvQuKy', 'wXvvQ6LO', 'wXpHNjw9'],
               ['wXYr2lVk', 'wXXj7iDP', 'wXXXIsQr', 'wXQbXKz6', 'wXN3tMp1', 'wXMfZV5N', 'wXvnlWej', 'wXSDyEaW',
                'wXQ7mM78', 'wXMPvojh', 'wXMjo-8G', 'wXLfZtO6', 'wXN3tMp1'],
               ['wXr_jZmX', 'wXr7D0AM', 'wXrzjhxL', 'wXrfjQNe', 'wXrnihqT', 'wXrjyqm5', 'wXr3CD4h', 'wXrnSZsy',
                'wXrTieP7', 'wXLfZtO6', 'wXgHVwkc', 'wXdvewsV', 'wXrfxZeg', 'wXrLB7Zo', 'wXprtX71', 'wXrHhjtO',
                'wXrzwKBt', 'wXqz-RlY', 'wXq_fp7F', 'wXq7Po7n', 'wXq7fC73', 'wXqzvRSW', 'wXqf_PQ3', 'wXML2vCd'],
               ['wXv3aQrv', 'wXvn6ONM', 'wXvfaG0M', 'wXvf6LIr', 'wXvjJBg_', 'wXvL6M-0', 'wXv7p2cd', 'wXv3poSs',
                'wXvz5kUz', 'wXvrZz0_', 'wXv_YVCb', 'wXLfZtO6', 'wXvX5Hgi', 'wXvz3Ptg', 'wXvHJUU-', 'wXvr4fB7',
                'wXvnlWej', 'wXv_YUrK', 'wXv7Id05', 'wXv7IYOV', 'wXvfYfLo', 'wXv7Y3AV', 'wXvT4_pE', 'wXvPovRt'],
               ['wXoDui-2', 'wXoT9yTg', 'wXmTQKw1', 'wXormLxu', 'wXMX-NNQ', 'wXo7kUfB', 'wXon0rt_', 'wXozT-3V',
                'wXnvYjEc', 'wXnTn9D6', 'wXnLH7Cz', 'wXn_2HV_', 'wXnPGou9', 'wXnPVSNo', 'wXuG0sl3', 'wXnjAs7X',
                'wXm38mLv', 'wXmnj5Oh', 'wXmfjQ2h', 'wXm_wXuD', 'wXlPOUmy', 'wXcfHkmx', 'wXQ_62cx', 'wXUD3qyx']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": post_token_list})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col2": tokens_list})

query_bounce = []

def query_bounce_checker(dataset_clicked, dataset_loaded, col1, col2):
    for i in dataset_clicked[col1]:
        for j in i:
            [query_bounce.append(k) for k in dataset_loaded[col2] if j in k]
    return query_bounce


query_bounce_checker(df1, df2, "col1", "col2")
```

`i`, `j`, and `k` values are used to access and compare the elements and sub-elements of the two respecting columns.
Speed is a contributing factor for me, and the function written here is not fast enough for a dataset of this size.

Comment: So to confirm, you want to get a list of all values in df1["col1"] which are also present in df2["col2"]?

Comment: @Shubham Periwal yes that is correct. The loops are to access the values since the lists are nested.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what your current function is producing. Because the values in `df1['col1'` which are also present in `df2['col2']` would be `['wXmTQKw1' 'wXvnlWej']` not `[['wXoDui-2', 'wXoT9yTg', 'wXmTQKw1', 'wXormLxu', 'wXMX-NNQ', 'wXo7kUfB', 'wXon0rt_', 'wXozT-3V', 'wXnvYjEc',...`

Comment: You appear to be loading the entire list from col2 into query_bounce on each match, instead of the single matching value

Comment: @HenryEcker that's right. I forgot to mention that eventually the list which the element in col1 has been found inside should be singled out and added to the query_bounce for further analysis.

Comment: @Chris you are right, I explained this to HenryEcker just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is actually what you want, this should be pretty fast.

```
import numpy as np

np.intersect1d(np.hstack(df1.col1),np.hstack(df2.col2))
```

Output

```
array(['wXmTQKw1', 'wXvnlWej'], dtype='<U8')
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it is what you want. If you just want to check which values in df1 also exist in df2, you can transform two dataframes into arrays and use `np.in1d()` to do so.

Try this:

```
array1 = np.array((','.join(df1['col1'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)))).split(','))
array2 = np.array((','.join(df2['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)))).split(','))
print(array1[np.in1d(array1,array2)])
```

Output:

```
['wXmTQKw1' 'wXvnlWej']
```